# Robotium: Wifi networks testing on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, robotium

Is it possible to test wifi related tests on Android Emulator. That means in my application I have a scenario which will search a particular wifi network available and then connect to it entering password in the password field. Is it possible using Emulator only. Can it be done so that Emulator will access the wifi adapter of laptop and the available networks will be shown in the search list in Emulator.

N:B

I am using Robotium version 4.3 with ADT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
There is no APIs to access the system WiFi adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't enable WiFi on your android Emulator because the emulator is actually a virtual OS running on pc, which is using your laptop/pc WiFi connection.

If you want to search for WiFi networks, you better search on a real device.